# Fullcalendar v4 not highlighting selected days

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using Fullcalendar v.4 and in one project the days select properly when dragging, however in my current project they do not.  The code is mostly copied and pasted so I am not sure what I am missing here.  Even when I put an empty init function in the code as seen below, the highlighting doesn't happen, however the console log does print when I perform the selection...

```
import fullCalendar from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullCalendar_4_3_1";
import fontAwesome from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fontawesome_6_2_1";

renderedCallback() {
//console.log('bw: start renderedCallback');
if (this.fullCalendarInitialized) {
  return;
}
this.fullCalendarInitialized = true;

//set global vars
selfs[this.calendarId] = this;

//console.log('bw: fontawesome url = ' + fontAwesome + "/css/all.min.css")
Promise.all([
  loadStyle(this, fontAwesome + "/css/all.min.css"),
  loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.js"),
  loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.css")
])
  .then(() => {
    //got to load core first, then plugins
    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.js"),
      loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.css"),
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.js"),
      loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.css"),
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.js"),
      loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.css"),
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/interaction/main.js"),
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment/main.js"),
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment-timezone/main.js"),
    ]).then(() => {
      console.log("init");
      this.init();
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new ShowToastEvent({
        title: "Error loading",
        variant: "error"
      })
    );
  });

}

init() {
try {
  var calendarEl = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${this.calendarId}"]`);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ["dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list", "interaction", "moment"],
    views: {
      listDay: { buttonText: "list day" },
      listWeek: { buttonText: "list week" },
      listMonth: { buttonText: "list month" },
      timeGridWeek: { buttonText: "week time" },
      timeGridDay: { buttonText: "day time" },
      dayGridMonth: { buttonText: "month", eventLimit:4 },
      dayGridWeek: { buttonText: "week" },
      dayGridDay: { buttonText: "day" }
    },
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
    },

    loading: isLoading => {
      if(isLoading === false) {

      }
    },
    
    eventRender: info => {

    },

    eventClick: info => {
      
    },

    //eventMouseEnter: info => {console.log("mouse enter", info)},

    select: info => {
      console.log('bw: calendar.select, date range = ' + info.startStr  + ' - ' + info.endStr);
    },

    dateClick: info => {
      
    },

    datesRender: info => {
      
    },

    selectable: true,
    selectMinDistance: 10,
    height: this.height,
    aspectRatio: this.aspectRatio,
    defaultDate: this.defaultDate,
    eventLimit: true,
    editable: true,
    droppable: false,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    displayEventTime: true,
    displayEventEnd: true,
    
  });
  this.calendar.uniqueId = this.calendarId;
  this.calendar.render();
}
catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

}

Update: It appears that whatever is happening is stopping the calendar from working after selecting days.  So once select occurs I can no longer switch the view from dayGrid to week or any functions on any other built in buttons.  But I don't know how to display whatever error is happening in the console.  I have try/catch statements everywhere and nothing seems to work.